# Import custom css webpack loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I want to include a custom .css in the main.tsx file I have. This is the error I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/style.css 1:20
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

The custom .css file I use has this content:

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

And here is the module of my webpack file:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader'
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I tried also adding `style-loader` and get the same error. The webpack version is 4.16.5.

Answer (score 0):

It’s choking on the pseudo-element. It could be that it doesn’t support the double-colon syntax. It may be a red herring, but try single colons: `input[type="number"]:-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]:-webkit-inner-spin-button`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `style-loader` with `minimize-loader` and use can do something like below:

```
module: {
 rules: [
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    'style-loader','css-loader?minimize-loader','postcss-loader'
   ]
  },
 ]
}
```

And even not working then add `postcss-loader` as well.